# Catch method getting always executed (Javascript)

Tags: javascript

I'm having trouble understanding why this `.catch` method gets executed even though the promises from the before mentioned async functions are successfully fulfilled.

I'd like for my web-app to display an error message to the user in case of failure in retrieving data from the server.

Here's the code:

```
async function main() {
await asyncSendDataToServer()
.then(result = await asyncReceiveDataFromServer())
.catch(toggle('error'));}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you are immediately executing the function, you should pass in an anonymous function handling the error:

```
.catch((error) => toggle('error'))
```

Also, the `then` statement is wrong, as it's not a function. This is a proper way with async/await:

```
async function main() {
  try {
    await asyncSendDataToServer();
    const result = await asyncReceiveDataFromServer();
  } catch(error) {
    toggle('error')
  }
}
```

---

and without async:

```
function main() {
  return asyncSendDataToServer()
    .then(() => asyncReceiveDataFromServer())
    .then((result) => console.log(result))
    .catch((error) => toggle('error'));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the `>` from `=>` in the `.then()`, and all of `() =>` in the `catch`. Since you're using then/catch, the function need not be async anyway.

```
function main() {
  return asyncSendDataToServer()
    .then(result => await asyncReceiveDataFromServer())
    .catch(() => toggle('error'));
}
```

The async formulation is

```
async function main() {
  try {
    await asyncSendDataToServer();
    return await asyncReceiveDataFromServer();
  } catch(err) {
    toggle('error');
  }
}
```

Comment: I kind of disagree with the "the function need not be async anyway" part. Like, yes it doesn't have to be per spec, but it is returning a promise so at the end of the day it is still an async function, just not declared as such, therefore maybe being confusing. Some IDEs might also not pick up on that.

Comment: I wouldn't put `.then().catch()` in `async` functions, that's all.

Comment: Yeah, I agree with you, I wouldn't mix them up either. Just saying that by returning a promise, it is still an async function and should be marked as one (in my opinion and everyone is allowed to disagree). I prefer your second solution in terms of coding style.

Comment: Thanks to you both! I'm new to Javascript and coming from Python these concepts are quite hard.
So, to recap:
• An async function returns a promise.
• `.then()` method tells what to do if the promise is fulfilled.
• `.catch()` method tells what to do if the promise is rejected.
• `await` statement(?) takes a promise (async function) and execute it when fulfilled.
• `try {}` and `catch() {}` can be used for error handling.
Is everything correct or am I missing something?
Why using the `.catch()` method do I need to execute a function to call another?

Comment: I missed to specify that it's better to use `try{}` and `catch() {}` if I'm already using `await`, right?

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly suggest not mixing async/await and Promise/then if not absolutely necessary. Its just confusing (as you might notice).

```
async function main() {
  try {
    await asyncSendDataToServer();
    const result = await asyncReceiveDataFromServer();
    
    console.log(result);
  } catch(e) {
    toggle('error')
  }
}
```

If you actually want to write it in your style, here is the correct solution:

```
async function main() {
  await asyncSendDataToServer()
    .then(() => { 
      result = await asyncReceiveDataFromServer()
    })
    .catch((err) => toggle('error'));
}
```